# Converting numbers into strings

Tags: r, transform

I need to transform a lot of numbers into strings. The difficult part for me is that all strings must be 4 letters long. For example "1" must be "0001" or "234" must be "0234". I think this is a simple question, but I could not find the answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sprintf`:

```
> sprintf("%04d", 1)
[1] "0001"
> sprintf("%04d", c(1, 23, 123))
[1] "0001" "0023" "0123"
```

Comment: @user3184906, great :-) Do consider marking one of the answers as "accepted" if your problem has been solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to `sprintf` you can use `formatC`.

For example

```
> formatC(1:10, width=4, flag="0")
 [1] "0001" "0002" "0003" "0004" "0005" "0006" "0007" "0008" "0009" "0010"
```